# Assertion failed when fruitstrap after ./fruitstrap -d -b

Tags: ios, command-line, terminal

I am trying to launch my app on a device.  After I type in ./fruitstrap -d -b  it seems like it'll work, but after this line:

[ 11%] Copying /Users/"user_name"/"repo"/build/Debug-iphonesimulator to device

I get this:

Assertion failed: (AMDeviceTransferApplication(afcFd, path, NULL, transfer_callback, NULL) == 0), function handle_device, file fruitstrap.c, line 424.
Abort trap: 6

Has anyone else had this problem?

******Update**************

Okay, I was entering the wrong path.  I am entering the entire path now, but I am getting this now:

[ 60%] InspectingPackage
AMDeviceInstallApplication failed: -402653103

[This forum](http://www.nme.io/community/forums/bugs/fruitstrap-randomly-fails/) is helpful, but still it hasn't helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was entering the wrong path.  I should have entered the path for a file with the .app suffix.